# Some problems with Unity interface dialog box buttons

Tags: 11.04, unity, compiz, interface

Hello I've installed Ubuntu 11.04 on my laptop, I'm running Unity with no problem except sometimes when I open a dialog box, for instance, the properties of a file, the buttons close and help located at the bottom of window don't work when I click on them. I have to move me with keyboard tab button and press enter or use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + (the first letter of button).

Fortunately this case is easy because I can close the windows doing click over 'X' button window(this always work) too. But sometimes it happens on others dialog box windows of another programs and it's a waste of time have to move with tab key or whatever,,, this happens with any button of unity windows interface, for instance if you are using Gimp and you want to save a file it can be possible Save button doesn't respond to mouse clic, sometimes the same thing with buttons of System Settings(I.E synaptic button), simply the button doesn't respond, the rest of system remains working well when it happens, nothing crash apparently.

It occurs with no prediction on any button and window dialog box, I don't know whether is a unity problem or other thing! thanks in advance!

Sony vaio laptop - G210m geforce - 4Gbyte Main Ram, Core 2 Duo ---

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyway or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reason(s) why you want it open. Regards